# why margin-right: auto has effect on justify-content?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

The following is using bootstrap code version 4.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/requests/get">File Request</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/requests/send">Send Files</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/history">History</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/users">User Management</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-collapse {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.mr-auto {
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

I wanted to move the `ul` to the right, so I set `justify-content: flex-end` on `.navbar-collapse`. It didn't work at first until I removed `.mr-auto`.

I am wondering why `margin-right: auto` would have effect on `justify-content`?

Comment: In a flex container, `auto` margins take precedence over keyword alignment properties such as `justify-content` and `align-items`.